# Find all tags containing a string in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In BeautifulSoup, I can use `find_all(string='example')` to find all NavigableStrings that match against a string or regex.

Is there a way to do this using `get_text()` instead of `string`, so that the search matches a string even if it spans across multiple nodes? i.e. I'd want to do something like: `find_all(get_text()='Python BeautifulSoup')`, which would match against the entire inner string content.

For example, take this snippet:

```
<body>
  <div>
    Python
    <br>
    BeautifulSoup
  </div>
</body>
```

If I wanted to find 'Python Beautiful Soup' and have it return both the `body` and `div` tags, how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambda function in `.find_all`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''\
<body>
  <div>
    Python
    <br>
    BeautifulSoup
  </div>
</body>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all(lambda tag: 'Python BeautifulSoup' in tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')):
    print(tag.name)
```

Prints:

```
body
div
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) in combination with pseudo class `:-soup-contains-own()`

```
soup.select_one(':-soup-contains-own("BeautifulSoup")')
```

or get only text of element:

```
soup.select_one(':-soup-contains-own("BeautifulSoup")').get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<body>
  <div>
    Python
    <br>
    BeautifulSoup
  </div>
</body>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select(':-soup-contains-own("BeautifulSoup")')
```

##### Output

```
[<div>
 Python
 <br/>
 BeautifulSoup
</div>]
```

Comment: Wow, how'd you find that? Neither `soup-contains` nor `soup-contains-own` is in the Beautiful Soup docs. That said, this doesn't quite do what I need, as I'm trying to search for "Python BeautifulSoup" - that is, the combined text I'd get from running `get_text()` on the `div` tag. (In reality, `get_text()` would show up with a bunch of extraneous spaces, etc. but it's closer to what I need.)

Comment: Oh it is, just take a closer look *The SoupSieve [documentation](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/) lists all the currently supported CSS selectors, but here are some of the basics* - So you may could clarify your question a bit, cause it seems that you look for `BeautifulSoup` or a single string and the goal or result is not that clear too. Thanks

Comment: Ah, got it - I was looking at the [official BS documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), which doesn't mention that pseudo-selector. I have slightly updated my question to clarify that I am looking for the string even if it spans multiple nodes.

Comment: It is mentioned and linked in the original docs -  The use case is not really tangible, it seems more like a normal text search, don't understand the connection to bs4. anyway how about `'Python BeautifulSoup' in soup.get_text(' ',strip=True)` or `soup.get_text(' ',strip=True).find('Python BeautifulSoup')`